# How to delete VB code from an Excel sheet using C#?

Tags: c#, excel, vb6, automation

Does anyone know how to delete **all** VB code form an Excel workbook using C#?
This code doesn’t work. It removes first (last one) VBComponent, but rises ArgumentException on second one.

```
VBProject project = workbook.VBProject;
int componentsCount = project.VBComponents.Count;

for (int i = componentsCount; i >= 1; i--)
{
    VBComponent component = project.VBComponents.Item(i);
    project.VBComponents.Remove(component);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: In VBA, items in collections must be removed from count to 1 step-1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it with Sam's help. I suspect that each Excel workbook has some non-deletable VBComponents, hence instead of deleting them we can clear their content. It works now. Thank you Sam.

```
VBProject project = workbook.VBProject;

for (int i = project.VBComponents.Count; i >= 1; i--)
{
    VBComponent component = project.VBComponents.Item(i);
    try
    {
        project.VBComponents.Remove(component);
    }
    catch(ArgumentException)
    {
        continue;
    }
}

for (int i = project.VBComponents.Count; i >= 1; i--)
{
    VBComponent component = project.VBComponents.Item(i);
        component.CodeModule.DeleteLines(1, component.CodeModule.CountOfLines);
}
```

Do not forget to save your workbook afterwards

Answer (score 2):

have you tried deleting the first one n times:

```
VBProject project = workbook.VBProject;
int componentsCount = project.VBComponents.Count;

for (int i = 1; i <= componentsCount; i++)
{
    VBComponent component = project.VBComponents.Item(1);
    project.VBComponents.Remove(component);
}
```

You might need to tweak this, but i think the VBA collections are 1 based (might need to make the `project.VBComponents.Item(0)` instead.

EDIT:

I found [this post](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=93) which explains how to do it in VBA, but presumably its not too difficult to translate...

Comment: Yes, I've tried. Yes VB uses 1-based collections, so your code is working fine if not calling Remove. But I still getting ArgumentExcecption. I.e. I can delete 4-th element in the collection, but not others. I suspect that first 3 VBComponents are embeded (like first three workseets in a workbook) and cannot be removed... maybe I should clear their content instead of removing. Let me try :)

Comment: what does the code file look like?  does it have 4 'things' in it or just one?  What does it look like after you have removed everything you can, is it empty?  (perhaps in  a `try catch` block so you can ignore errors while you experiment)

Comment: edited my answer to add some information found on another site which might be useful...  They seem to use `On Error Resume Next` so i suspect some elements are non deletable

Comment: Thank you Sam, you gave me an idea! And it works now (see my answer). Thanks again!